# Redirect image url

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, url, https

I dont know  what this method is called.

I have an image url with HTTP and without format

url = http://imageurl.com/abcd1234/

the url contains a .jpg formatted image.

can I change the domain without having to upload an image in it?

something like the  example below.

ex = https://example.com/abcd1234.png/

actually i just need to convert HTTP to HTTPS for some reason in my program. because the image source has an HTTP url.

Comment: You're saying you have a url as a string and you want to change that string to a different url by changing the protocol to "https" and adding a ".png" extension?

Comment: i just need to convert HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: `ex.replace("http://", "https://")`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey like just passing the domain in the example only

Comment: @Graipher I've done that, but the domain from the source image does not support https

Comment: So you basically want to use HTTPS over a HTTP connection, probably because somebody told you to always use HTTPS? Sorry, if the server does not support it, you will not get a HTTPS connection.

Comment: @Graipher is there a way to pass an image from source, to my own domain?

Comment: Download it and host it on your domain (making sure you are actually allowed to do that)?

Comment: I don't understand the question one bit. Are you trying to download that image? Or upload it? Is your program the server or the client? Or is it neither, and you just want to perform a simple string operation? This is horribly unclear.

Comment: @Graipher maybe that's what i'll do. but is there any other way without re-uploading to my domain.?

Comment: @Aran-Fey 
I try to change the domain containing images with my domain without reuploading the image.